# Reports for Flutter test_driver execution

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I need to generate a report about how much tests was executed, how much failed, why test was failed. Is there some option to do it with `test_driver`?
We can generate json report for flutter unit tests with command `flutter test --machine`. Is there something same for `flutter drive`?

Comment: What about the logs that you get from `flutter drive` by default is wrong, i.e. what is missing? Could you share some more information (logs (actual vs expected), code etc.)?

Comment: Yes console output contains raw logs. But it isn't structured format, I mean like junit report or json report. It is not very easy to understand this raw logs when it contains hundred of tests. I am not sure it is easy to understand how much tests was executed and see fail reason for each test.

Comment: I understand now. Indeed, it seems strange that it does not have `--machine`. `flutter format` also has it. You might want to create a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new).

Comment: there is opened a feature request https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14134
but for now it's not possible to generate a report for driver tests :(

Answer (score 0):

Although flutter driver doesn't generate a full-fledged test summary report out-of-box, there's an alternative way to do it using [flutter_gherkin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gherkin#-readme-tab-) plugin. This plugin makes use of ATDD style of writing integration tests leveraging flutter driver and its methods.

Checkout the example from plugin's repo.

This plugin has a configuration file (just like instrumentation file in Google Espresso) which has a `reporter` parameter to specify json reporter that generates report in json format. 
Below is the content of generated json report:

```
[{
    "keyword": "Feature",
    "uri": "./test_driver/features/custom_parameter_example.feature",
    "id": "custom parameter example",
    "name": "Custom Parameter Example",
    "description": "",
    "line": 0,
    "elements": [{
        "keyword": "Scenario",
        "type": "scenario",
        "id": "custom parameter example;custom colour parameter",
        "name": "Custom colour parameter",
        "description": "",
        "line": 3,
        "steps": [{
            "keyword": "Given ",
            "name": "I pick the colour red",
            "line": 4,
            "result": {
                "status": "passed",
                "duration": 6000000
            }
        }, {
            "keyword": "Given ",
```

This report can then be converted into html report using `cucumber-html-reporter` per your requirement.

This approach sounds a bit tedious and the format may or may not be the way you want, because you might need to re-write your tests in `Given When Then` format in order for json report to be generated, but you may give this approach a try to see if this works for you.

Comment: what is the time format on "duration"? is it miliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, reports can be generated by setting paths in the test driver class, where the report path is initialized.

```
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test_driver.dart'
as integration_test_driver;

Future<void> main() async {
  /// Repports are generated on given path, once all tested passed,
  integration_test_driver.testOutputsDirectory =
      'integration_test/reports';
  await integration_test_driver.integrationDriver(
      timeout: const Duration(minutes: 60));
}
```

**Note: This will work using the flutter drive command.**

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I tried your suggestion, it will create a `integration_response_data.json` file in the 'integration_test/reports' directory that has `null` value regardless the tests are passed or failed. The following is my flutter drive command: `flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart --target integration_test/app_test.dart -d web-server --release --browser-name=chrome` that I execute using GitHub Actions. By the way, I am using Flutter v3.13.7.